# Using a DirectoryEntry, with a user/password, to access arbitrary Active Directories

Tags: directoryservices

I am trying to a DirectoryEntry to read from the configuration
partition of an arbitrary Active Directory using explicit user credentials.

I think the problem I am having has to do with whether or not the target active
directory has a trust relationship with active directory of the
current user. (the one executing the call)

I do something like

```
new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=test,DC=local",
                   user, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure) ;
// use a DirectorySearcher.FindOne to read properties.
```

and am finding problems with the user name format when accessing different active directories.  I have tried three alternatives:

- UPN:           admin@test.local
- DownLevel:     test\admin
- account name:  admin

For some active directories:  UPN and DownLevel work, but not the account name

For some: all three work

For some: only the plain account name works.

Questions:

- why does this happen?
- am I doing something wrong?
- is there some other syntax that will always work?
- is there a way to figure out which syntax to use?

In all the cases, the user running the query is a member of a different domain ... but in some cases the user might have privileges to the target domains.

Thanks,